# How to /give spawn eggs in 1.10 with a specific name and enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a one command and I want to give players a Ghast Spawn Egg enchanted with power 1, a lure of `Water, In The Nether!` and named `Nether_Water`.

I tried

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {{EntityTag:{id:"Ghast"}},display:{Name:Nether_Water,Lore:["Water, In The Nether!"]},ench:[{id:48,lvl:1}]}
```

but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have stray curly brackets around `EntityTag:{...}`.

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:"Ghast"},display:{Name:Nether_Water,Lore:["Water, In The Nether!"]},ench:[{id:48,lvl:1}]}
```